# How to add an img tag to menu links?

Tags: php, templates, drupal, menu

Please help me with my problem.
I have a table in database with `mlid` (menu link id) column and `path` column - every primary link menu has an image. I created my custom module which adds a file upload field to menu link edit form, and saves its `mlid` (menu link id) and `path` (path to image) to database.

My question is: how can I display my images in my menu items? I want just to add a `<img src="..">` tag for every menu item.
Code:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a>First menu item</a>
    // <img>HERE I WISH TO GENEARATE AN IMG TAG</img>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>Second menu item</a>
    // <img>HERE I WISH TO GENEARATE AN IMG TAG</img>
  </li>
...
</ul>
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you looking where to modify the source codes of drupal menus or you are writing these codes yourself?

Comment: Where to modify (add something) the source code of drupal menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a [preprocess hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7.x) in your module in order to load the image path into the `$variables` array that is passed to the template :

```
function MODULE_preprocess_menu_link(&$variables) {
  $element = &$variables['element'];
  $mlid = $element['#original_link']['mlid'];

  # Retrieve image source (if any) from database/original_link object.
  $element['image_src'] = _your_helper_function($mlid);
}
```

Then you just need to override the template function so that it outputs the tag according to whether or not an image source has been set.

In your *theme's template.php*, create your own THEME_menu_link() function (or if it's already overridden by your current theme, carefully add the logic into the existing one) - for example, the following overrides the [default implementation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7.x) for the Main menu) :

```
function THEME_menu_link__main_menu($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
  }

  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);

  if (!empty($element['image_path'])) {
    $output .= '<img src="' . $element['image_path'] . '" />';
  }

  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```